# TypeError: cannot read 'props' of undefined in Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, testing, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

Hello I to  create a test for a cancel button in a material ui based dialog window with Mocha and Enzyme and Chai but I get an error can read property of undefined.

My dialog window:

```
class DialogWindow extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
  }


  handleRequestClose() {
    this.setState({open: false});
  }


  render() {
    return (
        <Dialog
          onClose={this.handleRequestClose}
          open={this.state.open}
          render={({
            Icon,
            getIconProps,
            getTitleProps,
            getContentProps,
            getActionsProps
          }) => (
            <div>
              <Icon {...getIconProps()} />
              <DialogTitle {...getTitleProps()}>
                entry
              </DialogTitle>
              <DialogContent {...getContentProps()}>
                Are you sure you want to proceed?
              </DialogContent>
              <DialogActions {...getActionsProps()}>
                <Button onClick={this.handleRequestClose.bind(this)}>Cancel</Button>
              </DialogActions>
            </div>
          )}
          {...this.props}
        />
    );
  }
}

export default connect()(DialogWindow);
```

And my test for the cancel button I am not sure if I can access a child of child like this:

```
describe('Cancel button test', () => {
  it('cancel button on the dialog window works', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Provider store = {store}>
        <DialogWindow.WrappedComponent />
      </Provider>).dive();
    wrapper.setState({ open: true });
    const dialog = wrapper.find('Dialog').at(0);
    const cancelButton = dialog.find('button').at(0);
    cancelButton.simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.state().open).to.eql(false);
  });
});
```

Error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
      at Object.simulateEvent (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16\build\ReactSixteenAdapter.js:326:34)
      at ShallowWrapper.<anonymous> (node_modules\enzyme\build\ShallowWrapper.js:932:57)
      at ShallowWrapper.single (node_modules\enzyme\build\ShallowWrapper.js:1620:25)
      at ShallowWrapper.simulate (node_modules\enzyme\build\ShallowWrapper.js:929:21)
      at Context.<anonymous> (src\_tests_\components/D:\projec\src\_tests_\components\DialogWindow.test.js:48:11)
```

Comment: Is this exact error "can read property of undefined"? it just says property undefined but which property?

Comment: @Think-Twice I added it :)